# React Native: why are state variables updated only on hot reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

**The Scenario**

In my React Native app I have a tab navigator. In each tab I have a `<Checkbox>` component that is checked/unchecked according to a state variable, and you can toggle the checked/unchecked value by clicking the Checkbox. These Checkbox components look like this:

```
<CheckBox
  checked={this.state.a}
  onPress={() => this.setState({a: !this.state.a})}
/>
```

Each of the tabs is its own component with its own state, each containing the state variable `a`. Each `<Checkbox>` starts out 'checked', ie `this.state.a` is `true`.

**The Unusual Behavior**

Say we have tabs A, B, and C, all with `this.state.a` initially `true` (and each of their Checkboxes therefore checked). If I click the Checkbox in tab A, `this.state.a` in A becomes `false` and the Checkbox becomes unchecked as expected. BUT when I navigate to tab B, the Checkbox there is unchecked as well. `this.state.a` in B is still `true` for some reason. If I save one of my files, the screen hot reloads, and `this.state.a` in B will now become `false`.

**My questions are:**

1. Why does toggling the checkbox in one tab affect the toggled value of the checkbox in the other tabs?
2. How can the checkbox in B go from checked to unchecked when `this.state.a` doesn't switch to `false`?
3. Why does `this.state.a` in B switch to `false` when I hot reload the page?

Comment: Are you using one state variable for 3 checkbox ? it is unclear to me

Comment: @hardworker No, I am using a different state variable in each screen. They are called 'a' in each screen though.

Comment: Did you try naming them differently ? There might be an issue

Comment: @hardworker I figured it out actually; updating my original question with the solution. Thanks for looking into it for me.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience hot reload in react-native is not reliable. It's great if you just having style changing. In your case, since the hot reload designed for speed, it partially refreshes based on your changes. While it makes the b item false but not refreshes the components state. In this case, manual reload would be much reliable

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: SOLUTION: **

The code I provided above was a simplification of the actual project (since the proj includes proprietary code). Basically, `this.state.a` is actually a complex object that is several layers deep, and `this.state.a` in each screen is initialized like `this.setState({a: {...obj}})`. I thought that expression `obj` as `{...obj}` with the spread operator would copy `obj` to `this.state.a` independently in each screen, but since `obj` is several layers deep, `this.state.a` for all the screens all ended up referencing the same object (`obj`). The solution is instead of `this.setState({a: {...obj}})`, do `this.setState({a: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))})`, because that does a true deep clone (as long as the order or properties in `obj` doesn't matter).

Comment: We can't help you if you simplify. Please post your full code next time